# Heroku Debug Flag not stopping django debugging

Tags: django, debugging, heroku, disable

I'm currently have Django project in heroku but I tried to stop the debug mode but unfortunately it's not working.

First I tried to stop it from `settings.py`:

`DEBUG=False`

`DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)`

Both are not working.

I've also tried also to set `env` variable :

`heroku config:set DEBUG=False`

`heroku config:unset DEBUG`

Both also not helping.

I tried to assign wrong value the debug in settings.py for testing which caused to crash the deployment.

Hopefully some one can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is simply set the heroku value as follows:

`heroku config:set DEBUG_VALUE="False"`

Then in your settings.py test the string value that you stored as follows:

`DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')`

Since `DEBUG_VALUE` is set to "False", `DEBUG` will be False in production.

Comment: This generate some errors on deploying:
`File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 132, in _url
 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 423, in stored_name
 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'default.jpg'`

however I removed this MIDDLEWARE: _whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware_ and it was deployed but still seeing debug pages.

Comment: I did not understand what is the relation between whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware and debug variable.

Comment: There is no relation. It is a different error you are getting because your static files are not configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue resolved, actually there was two problems:

**- First one:**
I used

> from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

in my models file to get static file url

> staticfiles_storage.url('img/default.jpg')

Which causing a problem during collectstatic in heroku, some how djanogo was not aware where to find the manifest file for it so I removed it and handle this in the html template.

**- Second problem:**
I disable collectstatic according to the advise from [heroku-django-assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) but this made a big mess, I realized later that when debug is true static files will be served from `STATICFILES_DIRS` while if debug is False static files will be served from `STATIC_ROOT` so when I turn off debug it was trying to get the files from `STATIC_ROOT` and here is the trick when you do collectstatic manually files will be collected to folder called staticfiles (your settings will be overridden by heroku settings) while if you enable collectstatic heroku will collect static files to /tmp/ dir then your app in both cases will try to get the files from /tmp/ which not exist in case you did collectstatic manually.

conclusion:

- It's much better not to use static file url inside Django code.
- If you have any problem with collectstaic during deploying your project to heroku try to fix it instead of disable it.

I know this is a little bit long but hopeful it will be useful.